# trouble while parsing json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to react displayName in req

when I write

`console.log(req.session.passport.user._raw)`

the output is:

```
{
    "kind": "plus#person",
    "etag": "\"ucaTEV-ZanNH5M3SCxYRM0QRw2Y/XiR7kPThRbzcIw-YLiARoF22TMY\"",
    "emails": [
        {
            "value": "rajanlagah@gmail.com",
            "type": "account"
        }
    ],
    "objectType": "person",
    "id": "100428644453494579140",
    "displayName": "Rajan Lagah",
    "name": {
        "familyName": "Lagah",
        "givenName": "Rajan"
    },
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/100428644453494579140",
    "image": {
        "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "isPlusUser": true,
    "language": "en",
    "circledByCount": 0,
    "verified": false
}
```

Now the from this object I am trying to get `kind` (say)

```
console.log(req.session.passport.user._raw.kind)
```

then the output is `undefined`

Can any one tell my mistake?

Comment: Well i think you havn't posted full json string here

Comment: I don't know your problem, but I get the right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `req.session.passport.user._raw` a string? You may need to parse it first, eg:

```
var data = JSON.parse(req.session.passport.user._raw);
console.log(data.kind);
```

Comment: thanku boss.can u please explain it more as it is my first time with this type of promblem and i dont get the logic